# Ahead faulting of multiple anonymous pages

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, mmap, virtual-memory

I have allocated a large number of pages with `mmap/MAP_ANONYMOUS` which are used for a list that only grows.

Is there a way to make the kernel intelligently prefault multiple pages for me in advance before they are accessed in Linux?

The `MAP_POPULATE` flag seems to be a no op for `MAP_ANONYMOUS`.

I can of cause just loop over a pointer in the style:

```
for (i = 1; i < num_pages_to_prefault; i++)
    *((char *)pointer_to_current_page + i * sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE)) = 0;
```

But this is neither thread safe, nor particularly efficient because a new context change is forced for each new page accessed.

What I want is something like

```
prefault_memory(void * start_address, size_t length);
```

that will cause only **one** context switch and prefault a number of pages or leave them untouched if they are not mapped or are already in my resident set.

Comment: What about using `mlock`?

Comment: I've never used it, but maybe `madvise()` with `MADV_WILLNEED` or `MADV_SEQUENTIAL`?

Comment: @Macattack Thank you. `MADV_WILLNEED` is exactly what I needed. Linux seems to obey this advice. Faulting ahead in chunks of 4Mb has given me a 25% speedup. If you post this as an answer then I will give you credit.

Comment: @KerrekSB Tried it, is even slower then faulting every page in manually.

Answer (score 4):

The call you're looking for is `madvise()` with `MADV_WILLNEED`.

Comment: Darn it, only the newest kernels support this. It works like a charm on my dev system, but not on the cluster running older kernel versions. Will need something different for that